# Laravel Model binding many to many realtionship does not populate data

Tags: php, many-to-many, laravel-5.3

I have two tables with a many to many relation (Project and Center, the pivot table is ProjectCenter).

These are my models:

Project:

```
class Project extends Model {
    public function centers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Center', 'ProjectCenter', 'IDProject', 'IDCenter');
    }
    public function getCenterListAttribute()
    {
        return $this->centers->lists('IDCenter')->all();
    }
}
```

Center:

```
class Center extends Model {
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Project', 'ProjectCenter', 'IDCenter', 'IDProject');
    }
}
```

Controller -> edit:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $project = Project::find($id);
        $centerList = Center::lists('Name', 'IDCenter')->toArray();
        return view('project/add', array('centerList' => $centerList))->with('project', $project);
    }
```

And the view:

```
{!! Form::label('centers_list', 'Center*') !!}
{!! Form::select('centers_list[]', 
    $centerList, 
    null, 
    array(
        'class' => 'form-control ', 
        'required' => 'required', 
        'multiple' => true, 
        'data-placeholder' => 
        'Select a center'
   )
 ) !!}
```

But I can not select the data already stored previously.

For example: the project 8 (IDProject) has two centers (1 and 2) but the data is not populated in the multiple select:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you using the relationship?  You seem to just be querying Project and Center separately.

Comment: I use the relationship to recover the centers to which the project belongs. I currently have in the database a Project that is related to several centers. The idea is to recover this data and populate them to the view, the first and the second should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

You all time get same result **$centerList = Center::lists('Name', 'IDCenter')->toArray();** but you must be get product centers using query **with** model.

```
$project = Project::with("centers:Name,IDCenter")->find($id);
$centerList = $project->centers->pluck('Name', 'IDCenter')->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks @Davit for your response. $centerList must contain all possible options for the multiple select. If I do what you suggested, then in the multiple select appears only the centers selected (related) with the project. The objective is to show all the options and only select those centers related to the project. I have also tried passing the $centerList and another array with the $selectedCenters but it does not work either: {!! Form::select('centers_list[]', $centerList, $selectedCenters, array('multiple' => true)) !!} . I already solve the problem using a foreach.

Answer (score 0):

I already solve the problem using a foreach to select the related centers:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="centers[]" id="centers" class="form-control select2" required="required" data-placeholder="Select a center">
 @if($centerList)
  @foreach($centerList as $key => $center)
    <option value="{{$key}}" {{ (collect($selectedCenters)->contains($key)) ? "selected='selected'" : ''  }} >{{$center}}</option>
  @endforeach
 @endif
</select>
```